# How can I completely prevent core dumps?

Tags: kernel, configuration

Every few shutdowns a core dump file is created on `/`. How can I prevent creating core dumps completely?

`gdb --core=/core` output:

```
Core was generated by /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -noliste'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

I added these parameters to my configuration files:

to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
* hard core 0
root hard core 0
```

to `/etc/sysctl.d/60-own.conf`:

```
fs.suid_dumpable=0`
```

to `/etc/systemd/system.conf`:

```
DumpCore=no
```

Core dump files still exist (in 16.04.1).

Comment: correct @steeldriver see for instance: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/65244/comments/1 Make it an answer ;)

Comment: there is already `root hard core 0` after `* hard core 0`. I forgot to paste it here.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `fs.suid_dumpable = 0` will be overridden by apport everytime **apport** starts.

Similar to how ufw interferes with my efforts to follow hardening instructions apport also interferes here. This is how I found out:

```
$ grep -R fs.suid_dumpable /etc/ 2>/dev/null 
/etc/rc5.d/K01apport:   echo 2 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
…
/etc/rc4.d/K01apport:   echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
/etc/lynis/default.prf:config-data=sysctl;fs.suid_dumpable;0;1;Restrict core dumps;sysctl -a;url:https;//www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt;category:security;
/etc/init.d/apport: echo 2 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
/etc/init.d/apport: echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
```

So to prevent core dumps and keep fs.suid_dumpable at 0 you have to disable apport:

```
sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```